# Session in not passed between pages c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working with VS 2013 and Mysql, in one of my pages I put select query in a gridview in this view and I have a button for each row so that if I press a row button I have a new window opening that has the colum Id (which is the first colum ) from the gridview.

the grid view button code:

```
                     <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField ><ItemTemplate><asp:Button ID="gridbutton" runat="server" Text="Plus de détails" OnClientClick="basicPopup();return false;" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' OnClick="button_click" /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

          </Columns>
```

the code of the button_click method:

```
 protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button gridbutton = sender as Button;
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(gridbutton.Attributes["RowIndex"]);
        string n = "l'index" + rowIndex + "";
     Session["idProjet"] = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        //string idProjet = Convert.ToString(Session["idProjet"]);
       // Alert.Show(idProjet);

    }
```

I just used the two last lines to make sure that I'm getting the value, and I'm getting the right value.
And this is the code from the second page where I want to get the session value:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                string idProjet = Convert.ToString(Session["idProjet"]);
                Alert.Show(idProjet);

        }
```

But all I'm getting is an empty result.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but you really should be using the query string to pass data between pages.  Session state is not the way to go in this scenario.

Comment: Doesn't the "return false;" in OnClientClick prevent the request from being sent to the server?

Comment: I don't think so cuz I already used the same thing in other pages and the variable session gets passed from one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

In you button code you have both onclientclick and click event.

In you clickclick event I guest you are opening the different page. Note that client click executes first. So the new page already gets opened. Your server side event executes later. That is why the session is not available in the new form.

```
<asp:Button ID="gridbutton" runat="server" Text="Plus de détails" OnClientClick="basicPopup();return false;" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' OnClick="button_click" />
```

In this case you have to pass the idProject as query string to the new page.